# Perl installation broken

Tags: perl

I can't install any modules in my perl 5.8.8. I get this error message trying to install anything:

```
Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Copy.pm line 83.
Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Copy.pm line 83.
Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Copy.pm line 83.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN.pm line 51.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN.pm line 51.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/App/Cpan.pm line 183.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/App/Cpan.pm line 183.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/cpan line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpan line 8.
```

Please help. I've tried googling, but most of the hits assume its about `use strict`. In my case, it seems I have a broken installation.

Comment: I can't your question. What can't you modules?

Comment: Not saure what the problem is, but initially I was tryiing to install Net::SFTP::Foreign. Got the error. Did some googling, one suggestion was to try to reintall Bundle::CPAN. Same error.

Comment: Either your core perl installation is broken and your Config.pm is trashed, or something *else* installed a Config.pm that's hiding Perl's. What does `perl -MConfig -le 'print $INC{"Config.pm"}'` output?

Comment: I get this: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Config.pm

Comment: This version of Perl was released somewhere around the Early Stone Age.  Are you sure you can't install a newer Perl alongside this one instead?  (Oracle, right?)

Comment: What version of CPAN are you using?

Comment: To find out if you have several `Config.pm`'s in your path, try: `perl -lwe 'for (map "$_/Config.pm", @INC) { print if -e }'` If you get more than one hit, that's probably not good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`File::Copy`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aCopy) is doing this:

```
use Config;
```

and later

```
if ((($Config{d_symlink} && $Config{d_readlink}) || $Config{d_link}) &&
```

If there is a file named `Config.pm` in [`@INC`](http://p3rl.org/var#%40INC) (including in the directory you are running your code), it will take precedence over Perl's built in [`Config`](http://p3rl.org/Config) module, and `File::Copy` will no longer be given a `%Config` hash, so `File::Copy` will break.

The solution is to name the offending module something else.

Comment: I did a search and found several copies of Config.pm scattered about my system. Is there anyway to determine which one is at fault? Should I assume the first directory in INC where Config.pm is the one at conflict? Current directory not withstanding.

Comment: @user675712 - `perl -MConfig -e 'print $INC{"Config.pm"}'` will tell you which `Config.pm` is being loaded.

Comment: I just renamed the first occurrence of Config.pm (based on INC) and was able to get into the cpan shell, which I couldnt' do before, so I think this issue is solved, but now I have a memory error:  ...Cannot allocate memory... I'll likely just need to stop some daemons, Apache, mySQL, etc. But that will have to wait until later. In any case, this issue is solved, at least. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Just a followup. I did eventually get everything installed and my system is running just fine now. So this solution, to rename the offending module, is indeed the fix.

Comment: @user675712 I would still like to understand how this happened. It shouldn’t be getting something in the cwd before the rest of `@INC`, so should have been fine.  Maybe a `PERL5LIB` envariable that prefixed `@INC` to include the offending directory?