# Perl on Eclipse (EPIC plugin) vs standalone: Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl, epic

I have a large project requiring maintenance. If I run the file on cmd, it works fine

```
perl entry.pl
```

However if I run with Eclipse (using EPIC plugin for Perl), it throws the following error

```
Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name at C:/Perl64/lib/Errno.pm line 11
```

I noticed the project includes a file called config.pm. Notice that 'c' is lower case in config.pm, but upper case in "%Config". I thought perl was case sensitive. I guess one solution would be renaming config.pm and all its references to something else (as suggested in [Perl installation broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534674/perl-installation-broken)).

Is there a way to fix this other than renaming all references to config.pm ?

Why does it work when run on cmd, but not on Eclipse?

Comment: It's complaining about a `%Config` variable, not the `config.pm` module. Them being named the same is a coincidence. You probably just need to set the correct working directory in Eclipse (which I am not familiar with, sorry).

Comment: @AKHolland After I renamed config.pm and all its references, it worked, but I am looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: The %Config that lib/Errno.pm was expecting was in lib/Config.pm. your config.pm probably messed with the namespace enough to accidentally confuse the compiler.  Glad you worked it out.

Comment: What confuses me is why they run differently on Eclipse and cmd (invoking perl)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would say that the are differences list of folders that perl uses to search for modules (perl has a list compiled in, and you add to it using the PERL5LIB variable, the 'use lib' pragma, and the -I command line option).  Either they have differing entries, differing numbers of entries, or are in different order (order matters).

Comment: So you can write a perl program that displays the value:  user Data::Dumper; print "$ENV{PERL5LIB}\n"    and run it from the command line, and from eclipse, and note the differences.

Comment: I think don't have that environment variable set.. When i run on commandline I get nothing, when on eclipse i get "Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"PERL5LIB"} in concatenation (.) or string at C:/workspace/Test_project/entry.pl line 4.

Comment: OK so I resolved this issue by creating a folder 'MyMods' and moved config.pm to MyMods. In the package definition I used package MyMods::config. I replaced all instances of use config, with use MyMods::config. This turned out to be the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I resolved this issue. I thought I would answer, so that it can help somebody else.

On Eclipse for some reason, having a config.pm 'collided' with the perl built in Config.pm, although the 'c's are different cases. If config.pm is part of a large project, renaming all references to the class config to something else is extremely difficult. The easiest is to move config.pm to a new directory (say MyMod) and have

```
package MyMod::config;
```

in config.pm

With this , I only need to change `use config` to

```
use MyMod::config;
```

This solution works on both EPIC and outside (on command line)