# Perl in Intellij IDEA: Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %Config"?) lib.pm

Tags: perl, intellij-idea

I'm developing a large perl module which works like a charm when running from Terminal. When running i with Intellij IDEA CE, the following error pops up. This happens in all major versions of the software.

My programm starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature qw (say);

use Getopt::Long;

use lib 'lib';
die('this is a test');
...
```

Perls own lib.pm starts like this

```
package lib;

# THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED FROM lib_pm.PL.
# ANY CHANGES TO THIS FILE WILL BE OVERWRITTEN BY THE NEXT PERL BUILD.

use Config;

use strict;

my $archname         = $Config{archname};
my $version          = $Config{version};
my @inc_version_list = reverse split / /, $Config{inc_version_list};

our @ORIG_INC = @INC;   # take a handy copy of 'original' value
our $VERSION = '0.65';
...
```

In Intellij IDEA this leads to

```
/usr/bin/perl -I/home/user/git/mytool/lib -I/home/user/git/mytool/lib/Download /home/user/git/mytool/download.pl Digi20
Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %Config"?) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/lib.pm line 10.
Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %Config"?) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/lib.pm line 11.
Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %Config"?) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/lib.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /home/user/git/mytool/download.pl line 10.
```

I don't know where these -I params to the perl executable are configured. In the run dialog, i configured no params for perl.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTA + Perl 5.34. On my home office machine everything works fine, too. But on the office machine not. Syncing IDE settings home > office does not help.

Found another user having a [similar issue on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000596/perl-on-eclipse-epic-plugin-vs-standalone-global-symbol-config-requires-ex) but the error comes from another module. My Config module is already named Download::Config.

Comment: Have you installed other perls than the system perl: `/usr/bin/perl` ?

Comment: Nope. It's Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Perl 5.34.

Comment: *"which works like a charm when running from Terminal"* How do you run it from the terminal? What happens if you run the IDE command from the terminal: `/usr/bin/perl -I/home/user/git/mytool/lib -I/home/user/git/mytool/lib/Download /home/user/git/mytool/download.pl Digi20` ?

Comment: What is your `@INC`?

Comment: Aha! it works when  removing the -I parameters. But I don't know where I can disable them. They seem to be added automatically.

Comment: You seem to have conflicting names with Perl's Config and your own Download::Config. Since you add /home/user/git/mytool/lib/Download to your `@INC`, it may consider `use Config` to refer to `Download::Config`.

Comment: @INC = /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34 /usr/share/perl/5.34 /usr/local/lib/site_perl

Comment: I don't use `use Config;` I everywhere `use Download::Config;`.

Comment: @Powerriegel It's right there in your question, in the lib.pm module.

Comment: Off-topic tip: `use lib 'lib';` should be `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib "$RealBin/lib";`

Answer (score 3):

There's a module call `Config` that comes with Perl. It exports a hash named `%Config` by default.

The error is due to `%Config` not being exported by by `use Config;`.

I'm guessing a different module named `Config` is being picked up by `use Config;`. You can verify this using `BEGIN { print "$INC{'Config.pm'}\n" }` after the `use Config;`.

You should name your module something else.

---

That said, I suspect you don't actually have a module named Config. I suspect you have a module named Download::Config (which is perfectly fine), but `/home/user/git/mytool/lib/Download` is being incorrectly added to `@INC`.

Comment: I searched my code for `use Config`, but there is no occurrence. I always use the correct `use Download::Config`. The question is related to the repeated `-I` parameters added by Intellij.

Comment: Re "*I searched my code for use Config, but there is no occurrence.*", It's the 6th line of the second snippet you posted. /// Re "*The question is related to the repeated -I parameters added by Intellij.*", Already added to my answer to cover that.

Comment: Yeah! You are right, removing the `-I/home/user/git/mytool/lib/Download` it works. I now just need to find out why Intellij IDEA is adding them...

Comment: I can't help you with that since I've never used the program. If you find out, feel free to post an answer, or let me know and I'll add it to mine.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

Intellij IDEA adds the configured library destinations as `-I` param to the perl call. Mind the purple marker here in the picture. The Download folder was purple, too. That caused the error.

[image: Intellij Perl library settings dialog]

There is a similar setting in the project structure settings but this does not cause `-I` parameters being added.